# usage of MailMessage.From in dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, sendmail, smtpclient

```
                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxx@gmail.com", "password");
                smtpClient.Port = 587;
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                //mail.From = new MailAddress("xxx1@gmail.com");
                mail.To.Add("XX2@gmail.com");
                mail.Subject = "Test mail";
                mail.Body = "This is test mail, with test content";
                smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

In the above code, why **mail.From** is mandatory? even I specified mail-id in smtpClient.Credentials.

Even I specified **mail.From** with some mail-id, the receiver is not receiving mail from this mail address, instead receiving from **xxxxx@gmail.com** which I specified in **smtpClient.Credentials**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From is supposed to be the address from where the mail was sent.
This can be different from your Smtp credentials. Some servers will let you have a username that is different from your mail address.

Gmail shows the email address from where it received the mail. 
They do that so that users don't mistake getting the mail from someone who didn't really send it.
Not all email clients do that.

You cannot fake a from address to gmail. They will always show where they got the email from.